# How to transition between colours using jQuery click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-color, document-body

im looking to transition between colours when a user selects different radio button values. I already have a 'working' example at the moment with just the immediate changing of the body's background colour, however i tried to use the fadeOut() and fadeTo() methods, but to no avail.

here's what i have thus far, if someone could point me to where i should be altering and which method to utilise.

many thanks in advance!

**colourChange.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#goodRad").click(function () {

        $("body").css('background-color', '#90EE90');//LightGreen
        console.log("make body green!");
  });

  $("#okRad").click(function () {

        $("body").css('background-color', '#FFA07A');//LightSalmon
        console.log("make body amber!");
  });

  $("#badRad").click(function () {

        $("body").css('background-color', '#F08080');//LightCoral
        console.log("make body red!");
  });
});
```

Comment: Without jQuery: `body { transition: background-color 500ms ease }`

Comment: thats great! many thanks for that, i was kinda hoping to keep with the jQuery to learn more about it, but this is cool!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use css to `transition` `background-color`. I also reworked your jquery to a little, but all you need to do is add the CSS from this answer.

```js
$('input').on('change',function() {
  $('body').css('background-color',$(this).attr('data-color'));
})
```

```css
body {
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="color" data-color="#90EE90" type="radio"><input name="color" data-color="#FFA07A" type="radio"><input name="color" data-color="#F08080" type="radio">
```

Comment: excellent! just what i was looking for :).

did already have values for the input's (but don't need them, so can change to having)

Would there be another way of achieving the same outcome without using the .val() method?